# Reading a POP3 message via JavaMail returns only html

Tags: jakarta-mail, message, pop3

Reading a POP3 message via JavaMail returns only html

so i ask that how can i specifie the returns?
mean return messagefrom,messagedate and messagebody

and how can i put my results on a label or textarea

please some one can help me

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Receiver {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Properties props = new Properties();

    String host = "mail.newhoster.org";
    String username = "admin@newhoster.org";
    String password = "I_hffngh12";
    String provider = "pop3";

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Store store = session.getStore(provider);
    store.connect(host, username, password);

    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    if (inbox == null) {
      System.out.println("No INBOX");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("Message " + (i + 1));
      messages[i].writeTo(System.out);
      String olm = messages[i].getSubject();
      System.out.println(olm);
//      JFrame fa = new JFrame();
//      fa.setBounds(20, 20, 300, 200);
//      JLabel lb = new JLabel("hello every ");
//      fa.add(lb);
//      lb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
//      lb.setBackground(Color.red);
//      
//      fa.setVisible(true);
    }
    inbox.close(false);
    store.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: The data you refer to is all available via the `Message` API.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html) and look at the [JavaMail sample programs](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples) to understand how to use the JavaMail API to access the content of a mail message.  Note that you don't get to control whether a message contains html or not, the sender controls the content of the message.  If you get a message with only html content and you don't want to display it as html, you'll need to convert it to some other format yourself; JavaMail doesn't help you with that.